# xpdf returns error (status 127) on Windows with R

Tags: r, windows, xpdf

I have downloaded and stored xpdf files to a directory in my C: disk:

[image]

Moreover, I have included the path to the Environment paths:

[image]

However, I still get an error message:

[image]

Comment: I have more or less the same problem when running pdftotext through R. Always get a warning "running command [...] had status 127".